# Can I suggest autocorrect change "u" to "I"?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, gboard

My Hangouts typing often sees me missing <kbd>i</kbd> for <kbd>u</kbd> and moving on with a new word. If I correctly hit <kbd>i</kbd> autocorrect always capitalizes it to "I" and my sentence reads correctly. If I hit <kbd>u</kbd> however autocorrect does nothing. "u" is a valid letter and becomes a word once I lift my finger to start the next word. It is not, however, a valid word (and it's not in my dictionary nor contacts). Has anyone been annoyed by this AND found a way to stop looking a little crazy?

EG "No I was in the coffee shop" reads "No u was in the coffee shop" and the reader gets confused as to why I am asserting that they were in the coffee shop when they asked if I ran in the park yet today... even though I never use "u" to mean "you" it's still very confusing.

Comment: This annoys me, too. I constantly reject the autocorrect and drag it to the trash can, but it still suggests `u` when I meant `I`